# Reading from Address 0x0 in Ada

Tags: null, arm, ada, memory-address, armv6

I am running on a bare-board runtime, and reading data from address zero is a valid use case in my software. However, the runtime treats address 0x0 as `null`, and throws an exception in the following code when compiled with `-O2`. The code behaves as expected when compiled with `-O1`:

```
declare
  use System.Storage_Elements;
  type Byte_Array is array (Natural range 0 .. 3) of Interfaces.Unsigned_8;
  bytes : constant Byte_Array with Import, Convention => Ada, Address => To_Address(Integer_Address(16#00000000#));
begin
  -- Copy bytes to some other byte array in memory:
  other_bytes := bytes; -- Throws exception
end;
```

Is there any way around this problem?

---

**Details on my platform:**

- Ravenscar Small-footprint Runtime ported to Arm Cortex M1
- Running on softcore processor instantiated inside a Microsemi RTG4 FPGA

---

**Details on the failure:**

The previous code dies in my runtime in the `memcpy` function implemented by `s-memcop.adb`. The code is copied below, with a comment reporting the line which fails. I am unsure of the actual exception that gets thrown. All I can see is the the last chance handler gets called with the information `s-memcop.adb:52`, which is commented below.

```
 40    function memcpy
 41      (Dest : Address; Src : Address; N : size_t) return Address
 42    is
 43       D : IA     := To_IA (Dest);
 44       S : IA     := To_IA (Src);
 45       C : size_t := N;
 46
 47    begin
 48       --  Try to copy per word, if alignment constraints are respected
 49
 50       if ((D or S) and (Word'Alignment - 1)) = 0 then
 51          while C >= Word_Unit loop
 52             To_Word_Ptr (D).all := To_Word_Ptr (S).all; -- Last_Chance_Handler Called here :(
 53             D := D + Word_Unit;
 54             S := S + Word_Unit;
 55             C := C - Word_Unit;
 56          end loop;
 57       end if;
 58
 59       --  Copy the remaining byte per byte
 60
 61       while C > 0 loop
 62          To_Byte_Ptr (D).all := To_Byte_Ptr (S).all;
 63          D := D + Byte_Unit;
 64          S := S + Byte_Unit;
 65          C := C - Byte_Unit;
 66       end loop;
 67
 68       return Dest;
 69    end memcpy;
```

Is there a way to see the actual exception being thrown?

Comment: Reading from address zero may be a valid use case for your software, but does the "hardware" agree?

Comment: I can read from address 0x0 using gdb, and I can read from address 0x1 using the Ada code above, but not address zero. So yes, the hardware should be rwx at address 0x0.

Comment: Did you already try to catch the exception in the block statement (`declare`...`begin`...`exception`...`end`)?

Comment: @DeeDee I have not. I can easily catch it with `others`, but I am not sure exactly how to determine which exception got thrown at that point. The `Ada.Exceptions.Exception_Information` procedure is not available in my runtime. I suppose I could list out an exception handler for every possible exception to see which path is taken.

Comment: It seems you need a specific seuence of machine instructions. That is what machine-code insertions are for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got in contact with AdaCore and received a solution to this problem:

> If you compile at -O2 or above, then you also need to pass to the
>   compiler the  switch -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks because
>   -fdelete-null-pointer-checks is  automatically enabled at -O2 for the ARM architecture.

According to the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) the `-fdelete-null-pointer-checks` flag:

> Assume that programs cannot safely dereference null pointers, and that
>   no code or data element resides at address zero.

Since this is NOT true of my application, and I need to access data at address zero, I needed to disable this switch by passing the compiler the `-fno-delete-null-pointer-checks` option.

**Note:** I had issues when the optimization flags of my code and the runtime were not consistent. In this case, compiling my code AND the runtime with the `-O2` and `-fno-delete-null-pointer-checks` options allowed me to freely read/write address 0x0.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated**

Although not a Cortex-M1, the example below seems to work on both the micro:bit (Cortex-M0, ZFP runtime) and the STM32F407 (SFP runtime, same result, not shown).

**main.adb**

```
with System;
with System.Storage_Elements;
with Interfaces;
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is

   type Byte_Array is array (Natural range 0 .. 3) of Interfaces.Unsigned_8;

   Bytes : Byte_Array with
     Address => System.Storage_Elements.To_Address (16#0#);

   Other_Bytes  : Byte_Array;

begin

   Other_Bytes := Bytes;    --  Line 17

   --  Output via semihosting.
   for I in Other_Bytes'Range loop
      Ada.Text_IO.Put (Other_Bytes (I)'Image);
   end loop;
   Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;    --  Required to flush semihosting output buffer.

   loop
      null;                 --  Line 26
   end loop;

end Main;
```

**debug session** (Cortex-M0, using `pyocd` as server)

```
$ arm-eabi-gdb main
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.3 for GNAT Community 2019 [rev=gdb-8.3-ref-194-g3fc1095]
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
[...]
Reading symbols from main...
(gdb) target remote :3333
Remote debugging using :3333
0x0000020a in _start ()
(gdb) load
Loading section .text, size 0x4fc lma 0x0
Loading section .rodata, size 0x20 lma 0x4e8
Loading section .data, size 0x4 lma 0x4fc
Start address 0x20a, load size 1312
Transfer rate: 3 KB/sec, 437 bytes/write.
(gdb) b 26
Breakpoint 1 at 0x14a: file [...]/src/main.adb, line 26.
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Note: automatically using hardware breakpoints for read-only addresses.

Breakpoint 1, main () at [...]/src/main.adb:26
26      null;                 --  Line 26
(gdb) p/x Other_Bytes 
$1 = (0 => 0x88, 0x8, 0x0, 0x20)
(gdb) x/4xb 0
0x0 <__vectors>:    0x88    0x08    0x00    0x20
(gdb) p/x Bytes (0)'Address
$2 = 0x0
(gdb) p/x Other_Bytes (0)'Address
$3 = 0x20000848
(gdb)
```

**output** (semihosting, run in separate terminal)

```
$ nc localhost 4444
 136 8 0 32
```

---

**Note on the usage of `System.Null_Address`.**

Note that I previously used `System.Null_Address` to reference address `0`. In this case (and most of the time) this will work. However, `System.Null_Address` does not represent memory location `0` by definition. Hence, `To_Address (16#0#)` might indeed be more safe (see also [ARM 34/2](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12aarm/html/AA-13-7.html#p34) and [ARM 37.c](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12aarm/html/AA-13-7.html#p37)).

---

**Hints that might identify cause.**

Based on the provided information (unexpected invocation of the `SVCall` exception handler and different behavior depending on optimization level) I would suspect some memory corruption (e.g. because of writes to incorrect memory locations; in C often caused by dangling pointers; in Ada might be because of using "unsafe" language features like `Unchecked_Access`, `Unrestricted_Access` and the `Address` attribute).

Tracking down memory corruption can be very challenging as the (source code) location where the damage is done may not even be close to where you actually observe the problem.

The first thing I would start to investigate is the invocation of the `SVCall` exception handler. I would not expect an ARM `svc` instruction to be executed in your case. Some steps I would try (no guarantee this will bring you closer to the solution):

- Disassemble parts of the relevant code around near the problem (in your case `memcpy`) using `arm-eabi-objdump -d -S` and keep it as reference.
- Hook up the `gdb` debugger, load the program and inspect if the disassembly near `Other_Bytes := Bytes;` and that of `memcpy` is comparable with what `objdump` returned. Using my own example:

```
(gdb) info line main.adb:17
Line 17 of "[...]/src/main.adb" starts at address 0xca <_ada_main+10> and ends at 0xe6 <_ada_main+38>.
(gdb) x/14i 0xca
[...]
```

and

```
(gdb) info address memcpy
Symbol "memcpy" is at 0x300 in a file compiled without debugging.
(gdb) x/100i 0x300
[...]
```

- Set option to show disassembly per line and set a breakpoint just before reading the memory (i.e. `Other_bytes := Bytes;`). Again, using my own example:

```
(gdb) set disassemble-next-line on
(gdb) b 17
```

- Start the program (using `c`) and once halted at the breakpoint, inspect the disassembled instructions again. Continue step-by-step (using `stepi` and then subsequently pressing  `<return>` to repeat the last command) and monitor the processor instructions shown closely. Check if they are as expected (output of `objdump`). I expect that, at some point, the actual and expected program flow starts to deviate. Try to see if/where this happens at the level of processor instructions.

Comment: I am running a bare-board runtime, so there is no virtual memory or memory protection. I should be able to access address zero without an exception being raised. I would expect the code you wrote to work on my platform, but it behaves the same as yours does, even though address zero is a valid address.

Comment: Can you give some details on the platform (processor, SoC, board)?

Comment: I added some details to the question.

Comment: Interesting. And could you share some details on the exact exception you see. For example, do you receive one of exceptions stated [here](https://github.com/AdaCore/bb-runtimes/blob/community-2019/src/s-bbcppr__armv7m.adb#L269)? (I assume you use/ported (parts of) the ARM runtime by AdaCore).

Comment: I tried to run the code on a Micro:Bit and there it seem to work. I can read the memory at `0x0` and the value read corresponds to the contents of the memory in `gdb`.

Comment: As DeeDee says.

Comment: I added some more details on the exception I see, which I am hoping may shed more light on the issue.

Comment: I compiled DeeDee's code for my board, and it indeed does fail on the final line. Looking at the backtrace in gdb I can see that the `SVCall` exception is thrown which, in my runtime, calls a `__gnat_sv_call_trap` assembly function which loops endlessly.

Comment: This is quite interesting. So it is a processor exception, but given the description in section B1.3.2 of the [armv6-m reference guide](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0419/d/DDI0419D_armv6m_arm.pdf#page183), I cannot (yet) infer the root cause...

Comment: It is way out of my league, but could it be possible that some configuration registers have an effect on the observed behavior ? (say  B3.5.3/B3.5.4 MPU Type Register, MPU_TYPE and so on for instance on the ARMV6 ref guide)

Comment: @LoneWanderer These might indeed be relevant registers. However, it’s somewhat surprising an `SVCall` exception is being thrown. This exception is, as far as I know, only raised when an `SVC` instruction is executed (see A6.7.68). This is very unlikely the case here.

Comment: I did some more testing today. I have found that compiling @DeeDee's code with `-O1` causes it to run fine. Compiling with `-O2` reproduces the problem I am seeing.

Comment: Based on the provided information (unexpected invocation of an `SVCall` exception handler and different behavior depending on optimization level) I would suspect some memory corruption. I updated the answer with some hints, but note that debugging such a problem can be very hard.

Comment: @DeeDee thank you so much for helping me look into this, and for your detailed instructions. I believe the SVCall issue occurred because I had inadvertently disabled interrupts during the entire execution of the program. When I fixed that problem, the SVCall issue never reappeared, but I still could not read/write address 0x0. I contacted AdaCore and received the solution that I have just posted. Thanks again! It is wonderful to know that there is knowledgeable Ada folk on Stack Overflow. Cheers.

Comment: @dinkelk You’re welcome! Glad you solved the problem. Thank you for sharing the final solution :-).